# Improving MSTest startup time with Test Impact enabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I'm using `MSTest with Visual Studio 2010`.

So far, performance has been adquate, but I've hit a real annoyance.  I've been trying to find a way to run test in a more granular way and it looked like Run Impacted Tests was the perfect option.  However, when I asked MSTest to start collecting Test Impact data, the time to run my unit tests tripled.  Right now that's not much time; there are only 11 tests and it takes <10 seconds to complete.  But I'm worried about scale.

I did some web searches, and I can only find vague reference to this problem.  I'm curious if this is expected behavior and if there are any tricks to speed it back up.